# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS will not boot

Tags: boot, laptop

I used my Dell laptop to compile a boot usb stick with another Ubuntu distro.  When I finished I tried to go back on to the Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS system on the laptop but all I get is a flashing cursor in the top LH corner of the screen.  I have run Boot Repair Disk but it only created a "paste file" with a caption that someone may be able to help if they review this file.
At the moment when I switch the laptop on I get the usual Dell start-up screen and then is goes to the flashing cursor and that's it.
I'm not a techie by any means so your help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers
Rambler1

Comment: In honesty it was a little while ago and I'm not sure exactly what I did.  As I recall I was trying to partition a memory stick and install another version of Ubuntu, I booted from a boot CD containing Mint and working in Mint I tried to create a bootable version of another Ubuntu distro but I can't remember which.

Comment: Is it possible that you made a mistake and formatted a volume associated with your system installation?  Without knowing what caused the problem, it's hard to guess how to fix it. There is always the one-size-fits-all solution which is to reinstall the OS.  You can boot a live session from installation media by selecting "Try Ubuntu" if you need to access the file systems.

Comment: It was a while ago, I'm not sure what I did.  I was trying to partition a memory stick and install another ver of Ubuntu, I booted from a boot CD with Mint and working in it I tried to create a bootable version of another Ubuntu distro but I can't remember which.  I thought it would be a safer way of working as I was not working on the Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and so less likely to do any harm.  When I run the Boot Repair it gives the option to create a "bootinfo summary" or to quit, there is no option with "reccommended repairs".  It gave me this web address :  http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/54829vFgjD/

Comment: I do need to access the files but thought that I may overwrite them if I ran anything else.  I have the disc with Mint, would that allow me to access the files?

Comment: I'd be the last to say that what you propose is impossible!

Comment: Any live session of Ubuntu will allow you to access file systems. Running a live session doesn't need to be installed and won't make changes to your installed system **unless you tell it to**.  From the boot repair output there were no operating systems found. If I had to guess, you made a mistake when flashing the USB and wrote over your Ubuntu installation instead. Be very careful what operations you perform even in a live session because even though a live session does not need to be installed, it's still a fully functional version of Ubuntu

Comment: OK, I'll take a look with Mint.  Should it come up as another drive in the File Manager?

Comment: Yes the file manager should be able to access any mounted file systems

Comment: OK another lesson learned, thank you for your assistance.